# Scala-Input with while and do

Tags: input

I have this code snippet:

```
val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Please enter a list of values separated by a comma:")
  val input2 = input.split(",").map(x=>x.trim).toList

  def chooseOption() = {
  val input3= scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Enter your command. You can choose between list, maxLength, averageLength and exit: ")

  input3 match{
    case "list" => for (entry <- input2) println(entry)
    case "maxLength" =>for (entry <- input2.reduce((x,y)=> if (x.length()>=y.length()) x else y)) print(entry)
    case "averageLength" => {println("%.1f".format(input2.map(_.length.asInstanceOf[Double]).reduce((x,y) => x+y)/input2.length.asInstanceOf[Double]))}
    case "exit" => {sys.exit()}
    case _ => println("unknown command")}}
chooseOption()
```

My Problem is that I only can type one time an operation like list,maxLength at my

> def chooseOption() 
>   but i want it to let the user enter as long as he doesnt enter exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going trough my questions I now have an answer to this question found on my own. 
Here is the same code but calling the function `chooseOption()` as long as the input is not "exit"

```
  val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Please enter a list of values separated by a comma:")
  val input2 = input.split(",").map(x=>x.trim).toList

  def chooseOption() = {
  val input3= scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Enter your command. You can choose between list, maxLength, averageLength and exit: ")

  input3 match{
    case "list" => for (entry <- input2) println(entry) ; chooseOption()
    case "maxLength" =>for (entry <- input2.reduce((x,y)=> if (x.length()>=y.length()) x else y)) print(entry) ; chooseOption()
    case "averageLength" => {println("%.1f".format(input2.map(_.length.asInstanceOf[Double]).reduce((x,y) => x+y)/input2.length.asInstanceOf[Double]))} ; chooseOption()
    case "exit" => {sys.exit()}
    case _ => println("unknown command")}} ; chooseOption()
    chooseOption()
```